# Pandas - Loop through groupby df and filter by intersection

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I am having trouble combining the following steps in Pandas: I have snapshots by date from 2 entities. I have found the intersection of objects between the 2 entities for each date, and these objects are stored in a list of lists (one sublist for each date).

I would now like to filter the original dataframes of each entity to only consider the intersections, so I am trying to use Boolean indexing to filter while also using groupby. See below for the loop I'm trying to build:

```
filtered_df=pd.DataFrame()
for date_sublist in range(len(intersect_list):
    overlap_temp=df_orig[df_orig['ObjectName'].filter(intersect_list[date_sublist])]
    bkln_overlap.append(overlap_temp)
```

I also tried the construct below as a test, where I was trying to only keep rows where the object name matched the particular intersection list:

```
df_orig[df_orig['ObjectName'] in intersect_list[1]]
```

Does anyone have any advice for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: If you could post a sample `df`, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data from the OP, I will use a simple example to demonstrate. I hope this is what you are after, or can at least modify it slightly to achieve what you want.

After reading through your OP again (along with your comments), I think you should be storing the intersection lists in a dictionary, like so:

```
intersections = {'01/01/2018': ['ObjectA','ObjectC'], '01/02/2018': ['ObjectA','ObjectD'], etc.....}
```

To achieve this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['01/01/2018', 'ObjectA', 0, 0, 0, 1],['01/01/2018', 'ObjectE', 0, 1, 1, 1],['01/02/2018', 'ObjectB', 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ['01/04/2018', 'ObjectD', 0, 1, 1, 0],['01/02/2018', 'ObjectE', 1, 1, 0, 1],['01/03/2018', 'ObjectB', 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ['01/01/2018', 'ObjectC', 0, 1, 1, 0],['01/03/2018', 'ObjectA', 1, 1, 0, 1],['01/04/2018', 'ObjectD', 0, 0, 0, 0]],
                columns=['Date','Object','x1','x2','x3','x4'])

         Date   Object  x1  x2  x3  x4
0  01/01/2018  ObjectA   0   0   0   1
1  01/01/2018  ObjectE   0   1   1   1
2  01/02/2018  ObjectB   0   0   0   0
3  01/04/2018  ObjectD   0   1   1   0
4  01/02/2018  ObjectE   1   1   0   1
5  01/03/2018  ObjectB   0   0   0   0
6  01/01/2018  ObjectC   0   1   1   0
7  01/03/2018  ObjectA   1   1   0   1
8  01/04/2018  ObjectD   0   0   0   0
```

Group by `'Date'`:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Date')
intersections = {key: list(set(grouped.get_group(key)['Object'])) for key, val in grouped}
```

Gives:

```
{'01/01/2018': ['ObjectE', 'ObjectA', 'ObjectC'], '01/02/2018': ['ObjectE', 'ObjectB'], '01/03/2018': ['ObjectA', 'ObjectB'], '01/04/2018': ['ObjectD']}
```

Then apply the filters from the intersections dictionary:

```
out = [df[(df['Date']==key) & (df['Object'].isin(val))] for key, val in intersections.items()]
```

Gives:

```
         Date   Object  x1  x2  x3  x4
0  01/01/2018  ObjectA   0   0   0   1
1  01/01/2018  ObjectE   0   1   1   1
6  01/01/2018  ObjectC   0   1   1   0
         Date   Object  x1  x2  x3  x4
2  01/02/2018  ObjectB   0   0   0   0
4  01/02/2018  ObjectE   1   1   0   1
         Date   Object  x1  x2  x3  x4
5  01/03/2018  ObjectB   0   0   0   0
7  01/03/2018  ObjectA   1   1   0   1
         Date   Object  x1  x2  x3  x4
3  01/04/2018  ObjectD   0   1   1   0
8  01/04/2018  ObjectD   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks. The intersection changes for each date instance, which is making it more difficult. So i need to loop through each grouped-by date dataframe with the specific intersection for that time period. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you have a separate dataframe for each date?

Comment: I have one dataframe with all of the dates. I grouped by date to create the list of object intersection lists. So I already have the intersection list for each date. I now need to filter each date group by the list of intersected objects

Comment: What would I do with the dictionary afterwards to fiilter?